# How do I filter an image collection from properties of one feature collection and metadata of another image collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I have a feature collection (fc) with 29 features. Each feature has a "date" property, in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", the same format used to filter images by the `filterDate()` function.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {date: '2018-01-05'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {date: '2018-07-04'})
  // 29 more features
  ]);
```

For each feature there is an image. According to the geographical location and the date stored in the "date" property (e.g. for feature 1, I have a Sentinel-2 image that overlays its geometry `ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781)` and that was acquired on a date close to the date stored in the "date" property `date: '2018-01-05'`).

In this way I have created a collection of 29 images.

**What am I looking for?**

Now, based on this collection of Sentinel images, I would like to obtain a collection of Landsat images that were acquired on dates close to the acquisition dates of the Sentinel images and that overlap geographically.

I have tried to solve this problem in various ways and have not been able to get a handle on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could map a function over your feature collection, `fc`, that filters the Landsat image collection according to the geometry and date-stamp of each feature, then returns the image with the closest date. Example:

```
var L = 30 ; // search window, +/- days 


var collect = ee.ImageCollection(
  
  fc.map(function(feature){
  
    var date = ee.Date(feature.get('date')) // target date 
    
    return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    
      // filter for location and date 
      .filterBounds(feature.geometry())
      .filterDate(date.advance(-L,'day'), date.advance(L,'day'))
      
      // set date difference between target date as image property 
      .map(function(image){
        var diff = ee.Number(image.date().difference(date,'day')).abs()
        return image.set('diff', diff)})

      // filter by 'diff' and return closest image 
      .sort('diff', true)
      .first()
    
  })
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the result I am looking for. I already did that in the first step. What I am looking for is another image collection that contains images acquired on dates close to the dates of the images in this collection that resulted from your script.

Comment: Thanks @IagoMendesdeOliveira for clarifying. After reading your question again, I now understand that you are looking to filter a collection of Landsat images that are a similar date to a collection of Sentinel images (correct me if I'm wrong). Sounds like you should be able to modify my answer-or your own similar code- to map over your image collection (Sentinel), rather than `fc`. Changes would include replacing `date = ee.Date(feature.get('date'))` with `date = image.date()`.

Comment: Thanks @korndog. It worked perfectly!